# TypeError: Cannot read property 'isTTY' of undefined

Tags: node.js, twilio

```
const accountSid = 'account_sid';
const authToken = 'auth_token';

const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
.create({
    to: '+94716220786',
    from: '+13022519234',
    body: 'Your verification code is ' + Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 
9000)
})
.then(message => console.log(message.sid));
console.log('receive');
console.log(Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000));
```

I'm trying to send sms using twilio. I have installed twilio latest version in my angular project.

> But when the project runs, it says that "Cannot read property 'isTTY' of undefined"

Comment: what is the version of nodejs you are using?

Comment: Can you show your full code? At which point do you call `isTTY` method? Also, are you aware that the verification code in the message-body is not the same than in the `console.log()`

Comment: @gypsyCoder I'm using nodejs version 8.9.4

Comment: @ochs.tobi this is my full code. This code is inside a function. I called that function when a button is clicked. consol.log is ok. I'm aware of that. My issue when requiring twilio and calling the method from the client variable.

Comment: @YasiruRandeepa are you using it from the client side? You can have a look at this issue : https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/332

Comment: @gypsyCoder yes. I'm using it from the client side. I saw that issue earlier. But I didn't able to solve my problem. I don't how to use twilio functions.

Comment: @YasiruRandeepa I think the workaround is to create a twilio function and use it. You can have a look here : https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions

Comment: I've edited your account details out of the question, if they were real I recommend you log into your account and generate a new auth token for yourself, otherwise attackers could still get your details from the history of this question and use your account.

Comment: @gypsyCoder Thank you for the help.

Comment: @philnash Thank you so much. I did't think much about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio Node library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) is not designed to be used on the client side. Mainly because that would expose your credentials and an attacker could then use your account. JavaScript is also editable on the client side, so sending a verification code could easily be edited and abused by an unscrupulous user.

Instead, you need to build a server side component that will make the requests for your client side. If you are building phone verification, then can I recommend you follow this [tutorial on account verification with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/tutorials/account-verification-node-express).

If you want to start a bit more basic, then I recommend the [quick start guide to sending and receiving SMS with Twilio in Node](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/node).

Comment: I tried those steps. But it is not work for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Finally I tried mentioned code from the server side. It works. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Great! Glad it's working. Hope the rest of your application goes well. Could you also mark this question as correct so that others can see it helped? Thanks!

Comment: I have marked question as correct. Could you please vote up my question to increase my reputation.